# Connection Timeouts with TFS

Tags: tfs

Is there a configured timeout for connections to the TFS server from a client?  We have intermittent connection issues, and it always seems like the ping rates to the TFS server are very high when it occurs.  If there is a timeout setting, how do you view/change it?

Comment: Are you referring to the Hosted TFS 2012 Service? Or which version of TFS?

Comment: TFS 2012, hosted on a Windows 7 box locally.  Version 11.0

Comment: "Locally" meaning you're running Visual Studio on the same box as TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a timeout setting in TFS...with the exception of SQL Server having a 60 minute connection limit (so if you're pulling a large mutli-gigabyte file you may hit a SQL limit). However if you're working with smaller files take a look at TFS Request Manager for looking at connection information. http://tfsrequestmanager.codeplex.com/

Does your environment have multiple application tiers behind a load balancer? If so has the stickiness setting in the load balancer been turned off?